# How to select ComboBox item depending on the value of binding variable?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I would like to ask, how to select Combobox item depeding on the value of the binding variable. For example bind boolean variable sex to bind value *true* to *male* and *false* to *female*?

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="male"/>        <- select if true
    <ComboBoxItem Content="female" />     <- select if false
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: If my value is true, then I want to selest item with content MALE. And also when it is false, I want to select item with content FEMALE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

```
<RadioButton Name="Female"
             Content="Female" 
             Margin="0,0,0,0" />

<RadioButton Name="Male"
             Content="Male"
             Margin="0,20,0,0" />

<ComboBox Width="100" Height="25">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Male" 
                  IsSelected="{Binding Path=IsChecked, 
                                       ElementName=Male}" />           

    <ComboBoxItem Content="Female"
                  IsSelected="{Binding Path=IsChecked, 
                                       ElementName=Female}" />                
</ComboBox>
```

As more universal solution you can use [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Provides a way to apply custom logic to a binding.

Example:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns:this="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"

    <Window.Resources>
        <this:MaleFemaleConverter x:Key="MaleFemaleConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <ComboBox Width="100" 
              Height="25"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=IsChecked, <--- Here can be your variable
                                      ElementName=SomeElement, 
                                      Converter={StaticResource MaleFemaleConverter}}">

        <ComboBoxItem Content="Male" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Female" />                
    </ComboBox>
```

`Code-behind`

```
public class MaleFemaleConverter : IValueConverter    
{        
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)        
    {            
        bool Value = (bool)value;

        if (Value == true) 
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue; 
    }            
}
```

Comment: It is working, however could you be so nice and give me a hint how to do it, if the source is not radiobutton, but variable my variable?

Comment: Seems like at some point you'd want to get that information from something other than code-behind.  Binding to a view model seems like a better idea--given we're talking XAML here.

Comment: @Peter Ritchie: Maybe it's a good idea, does the OP have any ViewModel, that is, he develops his application using MVVM style? I only gave a couple of examples, converter is one of the options. Besides, `from something other than code-behind.` - Converter is a part of View, in this case the MVVM pattern is not disturbed.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev yeah, hard to tell when the OP just posts XAML, I think I would assume some sort of view model.  But, OP seems to be happy